# Unexpected output from dplyr (if_else statement)

Tags: r, dplyr

I am having trouble trying to figure out why **if_else** is behaving the way it is, it may be my code or the way the data is structured.

Below is a snapshot of a database am working on and it represents a longitudinal survey of study participants in a trial with weekly follow up.

The variable **"survey_start"** represents the start of the study-defined one year follow up (*which we called **"survey_year"***).

I am trying to populate all subsequent entries for each participant, per survey year, with the entry "survey" followed by an underscore and the respective year, eg. survey_2014.

There are missing entries such as the participant represented here, wasn't available at the start of the 2015 survey.

I have written two codes, first one fails while the second works, the only difference being I have reversed the order in which the entries are populated in the second code (from 2007-2016 to 2016-2007) and removed the if_else statement for 2015.

Kindly assist in figuring this out...

```
    trialData <- structure(list(study = c("site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", 
"site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", 
"site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", 
"site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", 
"site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", 
"site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", 
"site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", 
"site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", 
"site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", 
"site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", 
"site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", 
"site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", 
"site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", 
"site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", 
"site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", 
"site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", 
"site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", 
"site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", 
"site_1", "site_1"), studyno = c("child_1", "child_1", "child_1", 
"child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", 
"child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", 
"child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", 
"child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", 
"child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", 
"child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", 
"child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", 
"child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", 
"child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", 
"child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", 
"child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", 
"child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", 
"child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", 
"child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", 
"child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", 
"child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", 
"child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", 
"child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", 
"child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", 
"child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", "child_1", 
"child_1", "child_1"), date = structure(c(16078, 16085, 16092, 
16098, 16104, 16115, 16121, 16129, 16135, 16140, 16146, 16156, 
16162, 16168, 16177, 16185, 16191, 16195, 16203, 16210, 16217, 
16225, 16234, 16237, 16246, 16253, 16262, 16269, 16278, 16283, 
16288, 16297, 16304, 16311, 16319, 16326, 16332, 16337, 16346, 
16353, 16360, 16366, 16370, 16381, 16384, 16395, 16399, 16407, 
16415, 16422, 16444, 16452, 16454, 16467, 16474, 16477, 16484, 
16490, 16501, 16508, 16514, 16520, 16529, 16533, 16539, 16550, 
16556, 16564, 16566, 16578, 16582, 16593, 16599, 16604, 16613, 
16620, 16623, 16635, 16636, 16654, 16660, 16666, 16673, 16681, 
16688, 16693, 16702, 16706, 16714, 16721, 16728, 16734, 16745, 
16749, 16757, 16764, 16769, 16778, 16785, 16792, 16805, 16812, 
16819, 16830, 16832, 16839, 16846, 16856, 16862, 16867, 16877, 
16884, 16890, 16898, 16904, 16912, 16917, 16923, 16936, 16938, 
16953, 16960, 16966, 16973, 16980), class = "Date"), year = c(2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L), month = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L), survey_start = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "Y", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "Y", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-125L), .Names = c("study", "studyno", "date", "year", "month", 
"survey_start"))
```

code 1 fails:

```
 trialData <- trialData %>% arrange(studyno, date) %>% group_by(studyno) %>%
mutate(survey_year = if_else(date >= date[survey_start == "Y" & year == 2007 & study == "site_1"][1] & date < date[month == 5 & year == 2008 & study == "site_1"][1], "survey_2007",
                     if_else(date >= date[survey_start == "Y" & year == 2008 & study == "site_1"][1] & date < date[month == 4 & year == 2009 & study == "site_1"][1], "survey_2008",
                     if_else(date >= date[survey_start == "Y" & year == 2009 & study == "site_1"][1] & date < date[month == 5 & year == 2010 & study == "site_1"][1], "survey_2009",
                     if_else(date >= date[survey_start == "Y" & year == 2010 & study == "site_1"][1] & date < date[month == 5 & year == 2011 & study == "site_1"][1], "survey_2010",
                     if_else(date >= date[survey_start == "Y" & year == 2011 & study == "site_1"][1] & date < date[month == 4 & year == 2012 & study == "site_1"][1], "survey_2011",
                     if_else(date >= date[survey_start == "Y" & year == 2012 & study == "site_1"][1] & date < date[month == 4 & year == 2013 & study == "site_1"][1], "survey_2012",
                     if_else(date >= date[survey_start == "Y" & year == 2013 & study == "site_1"][1] & date < date[month == 4 & year == 2014 & study == "site_1"][1], "survey_2013",
                     if_else(date >= date[survey_start == "Y" & year == 2014 & study == "site_1"][1] & date < date[month == 4 & year == 2015 & study == "site_1"][1], "survey_2014",
                     if_else(date >= date[survey_start == "Y" & year == 2015 & study == "site_1"][1] & date < date[month == 3 & year == 2016 & study == "site_1"][1], "survey_2015",        
                     if_else(date >= date[survey_start == "Y" & year == 2016 & study == "site_1"][1], "survey_2016","")))))))))))
```

code 2 works:

```
    trialData <- trialData %>% arrange(studyno, date) %>% group_by(studyno) %>%
  mutate(survey_year = if_else(date >= date[survey_start == "Y" & year == 2016 & study == "site_1"][1]                                                               , "survey_2016",
                           if_else(date >= date[survey_start == "Y" & year == 2014 & study == "site_1"][1] & date < date[month == 4 & year == 2015 & study == "site_1"][1], "survey_2014",
                           if_else(date >= date[survey_start == "Y" & year == 2013 & study == "site_1"][1] & date < date[month == 4 & year == 2014 & study == "site_1"][1], "survey_2013",
                           if_else(date >= date[survey_start == "Y" & year == 2012 & study == "site_1"][1] & date < date[month == 4 & year == 2013 & study == "site_1"][1], "survey_2012",
                           if_else(date >= date[survey_start == "Y" & year == 2011 & study == "site_1"][1] & date < date[month == 4 & year == 2012 & study == "site_1"][1], "survey_2011",
                           if_else(date >= date[survey_start == "Y" & year == 2010 & study == "site_1"][1] & date < date[month == 5 & year == 2011 & study == "site_1"][1], "survey_2010",
                           if_else(date >= date[survey_start == "Y" & year == 2009 & study == "site_1"][1] & date < date[month == 5 & year == 2010 & study == "site_1"][1], "survey_2009",
                           if_else(date >= date[survey_start == "Y" & year == 2008 & study == "site_1"][1] & date < date[month == 4 & year == 2009 & study == "site_1"][1], "survey_2008",
                           if_else(date >= date[survey_start == "Y" & year == 2007 & study == "site_1"][1] & date < date[month == 5 & year == 2008 & study == "site_1"][1], "survey_2007",""))))))))))
```

Comment: I think you can do this without this nested `ifelse` statements.  Create a key/val dataset and then do a merge

Comment: It is incredibly unclear what you want, but I suspect that because you have convoluted code, there is a hidden error lurking in your code. Until it is clear what you are trying to accomplish it is hard to help you.

Comment: Hi @akrun, kindly give an example for the attached dataset. Also, it's great you noted that because we expect additional datasets that span many years and I figured many if_else statements will present challenges..

Comment: @AidanGawronski, the attached dataset contains weekly follow up for that child from 2014-2016. Every year, a survey is conducted for the next 1 year with each child having a different starting date. I intend to group all entries falling within a particular "survey year" by marking them as e.g "survey_2014" (under variable "survey_year") for all entries that fall within the 2014 survey year. Also, given that a child's starting date is anywhere within the year, chances are the end of follow up will fall within the next year and the next one will start soon after the previous one has ended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @akrun commented, you can accomplish this by merging data rather than using `if_else`. The process goes something along these lines:

1. Create a data set containing only the visits that start a survey year.

   - define the start and end dates, along with the survey year label here
2. Join the starting visits data to the original data

   - keep the rows that fall within a survey year
   - select only the columns needed to identify a visit, and the survey year label
3. Join the result back to the original data.

And here's how you could go about doing that using `dplyr`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

# Modify the data so that there's an overlap of survey years,
# in order to demonstrate how to deal with it
df <- as_tibble(trialData) %>% 
  mutate(survey_start = if_else(row_number() == 52, "Y", survey_start))

# Pick out rows that start a "survey year"
starts <- df %>% 
  filter(survey_start == "Y") %>% 
  group_by(study, studyno) %>% 
  transmute(
    survey_year = str_c("survey_", year),
    start_date = date,
    end_date   = pmin(
      start_date + years(1),  # make sure that the survey year
      lead(start_date),       # ends before next one starts
      na.rm = T
    )
  ) %>% ungroup()
#> Adding missing grouping variables: `study`, `studyno`

# Join all starts to the visit data
years <- df %>% 
  left_join(starts) %>% 
  # Keep rows which fall within one year of a start
  filter(date >= start_date, date < end_date) %>% 
  select(study, studyno, date, survey_year)
#> Joining, by = c("study", "studyno")
```

Now `years` contains all visits that fall within a "survey year"

```r
# Join the year classifications to the original data
result <- df %>%
  left_join(years)
#> Joining, by = c("study", "studyno", "date")
stopifnot(nrow(result) == nrow(df))
```

We can also check the result:

```r
# Check the rows before and after each start
i <- which(result$survey_start == "Y")
result %>% slice(sort(c(i - 1, i, i + 1)))
#> # A tibble: 9 x 7
#>   study  studyno date        year month survey_start survey_year
#>   <chr>  <chr>   <date>     <int> <int> <chr>        <chr>      
#> 1 site_1 child_1 2014-05-01  2014     5 ""           <NA>       
#> 2 site_1 child_1 2014-05-05  2014     5 Y            survey_2014
#> 3 site_1 child_1 2014-05-13  2014     5 ""           survey_2014
#> 4 site_1 child_1 2015-01-09  2015     1 ""           survey_2014
#> 5 site_1 child_1 2015-01-17  2015     1 Y            survey_2015
#> 6 site_1 child_1 2015-01-19  2015     1 ""           survey_2015
#> 7 site_1 child_1 2016-03-07  2016     3 ""           <NA>       
#> 8 site_1 child_1 2016-03-17  2016     3 Y            survey_2016
#> 9 site_1 child_1 2016-03-24  2016     3 ""           survey_2016
```

Created on 2018-02-22 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Hi @mikko, thanks for the code, let me test it out on the larger dataset and get back if I encounter problems..

Comment: Hi @Mikko, I noticed that this line of code `end_date = start_date + years(1)` does not take care of participants who don't have a complete follow up, that is those without entries that span one whole year. So they might have 6 months worth of data for a particular year. Is there a way to take care of this?

Comment: Your example data has a case like that at the end, and it's handled correctly, isn't it?

Comment: The end date is only used to define the interval in which a participant's visits all get classified into that survey year

Comment: Explicitly, you check `date >= start_date & date < end_date` for each participant's each visit and each survey

Comment: Seems to be working, pardon me. Another problem, after merging `result <- df %>% left_join(years)` I notice that there are extra entries. At the start of a  subsequent survey year, line with the start date is duplicated and contains in the variable "survey_year" the survey year of the previous one..I hope am making sense

Comment: That happens if a new survey year starts before the previous one has ended, i.e. the next start is within one full calendar year.

Comment: Probably the easiest way to fix that is to make sure none of the survey years overlap in the `starts` data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165622/discussion-between-k-wamae-and-mikko-marttila).